# Use a custom sbt plugin from my project

Tags: scala, sbt

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a couple custom SBT tasks I've built as Plugins. They currently live inside my Build.scala file.
I would like to move them into their own `package/folder` `structure/files`. However, obviously, when I do this and try to import them (say, import `org.myorg.MyPlugin`) it fails because it can't be found (it's not built yet).

Is there any way I can achieve this without packaging my custom Plugins into a jar?

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `project/` directory is itself an sbt project.  So, you can put files in `project/src/main/scala/org/myorg/MyPlugin.scala`.

Comment: Awesome! Did not know that, but looking at it now it makes total sense. Thanks!! :)